# Sum across sheets with multiple conditions

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have two sheets in the same spreadsheet: "Quest 1.1" and "Quest 1.2".

[image]

[image]

On the respective columns in QUEST 1.2, I want to sum the total revenue for each company based on the year in the date column in QUEST 1.1. I tried using

`=SUM(FILTER(FILTER('QUEST 1.1'!C1:C11,YEAR('QUEST 1.1'!B1:B11)=2015),A2:A11="Company A"))` but I  got a "Formula parse error".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can probably do a SUMIFS() to sum only when column A and row 1 match your criteria. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I added a header row to Quest1.1. (note the difference in offset). You should be able to tweak it to fit your needs fairly easily. It basically tells Google sheets that, SUM the `Amount` if the company matches column A AND if the date is on or greater than YEAR-01-01 and on or before YEAR-12-31.

Put the following into cell `B2` and `fill down` and `fill right` as needed.

```
=SUMIFS('Quest 1.1'!$C$2:$C$12,'Quest 1.1'!$A$2:$A$12,$A2,'Quest 1.1'!$B$2:$B$12,">="&DATE(RIGHT(B$1,4),1,1),'Quest 1.1'!$B$2:$B$12,"<="&DATE(RIGHT(B$1,4),12,31))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I finally got your code to work, just had to replace the commas with semicolons. I understood everything you did but still don't understand why the YEAR function doesn't work (it returns 0 for the Revenues).

Comment: That's great to hear. By YEAR function do you mean the one you had above, or the Date(RIGHT(B$1,4),12,31) Part?. Side note: I noticed that you are probably using the European number formatting (which is different from the Canadian locale I use), but I didn't know that the formula needs to be entered differently as well!

Comment: I was talking about the  one I had tried above (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093061?hl=en), the one you used I understood but it seems like the code could be simplified using YEAR(date).

Comment: The function YEAR works on a single cell, but you try to apply it to an array. I think that's why it is generating an error.